# Logging stdout and stderr for several commands in backticks

Tags: perl

I need to logging stdout and stderr for several commands in backticks.

```
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("test_app");
...
my $log;
$log = `service someservice restart`;

$logger->info("someservice: $log");

$log = `~/scripts/test.pl param1`;
$logger->info("test.pl: $log");

$log = `~/scripts/script.pl param2`;
$logger->info("script.pl: $log");

$log = `~/scripts/env.pl param3`;
$logger->info("env.pl: $log");

$log = `~/scripts/monitor.pl param4`;
$logger->info("monitor.pl: $log");
```

In this case only stdout will be logged. How can I logged stderr too?

This code looks ugly. Is there way to write it more gracefully?

Comment: You can use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout. For example: ```$log = `service someservice restart 2>&1` ```

Comment: I suggest going a different direction.  Instead of using backticks, I'd use **IPC::Open3** so that you can capture stdout and stderr in separate vars.  The stdout is logged as info and the stderr is logged as a warn or error.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to wrap the execution and logging in a sub.  Create a hash of the items that are to be executed and pass a specific hash element (key/value) to the sub for it to execute and log results.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a noob in Perl. Is it possible to show small example?

Comment: Try `perldoc IPC::Open3` for detailed explanations and examples.

Comment: I'm interesting in sub and hash of the items.

Answer (score 2):

Following Ron Bergin's suggestion, here is an example using [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html)

**/tmp/log4perl.conf**

```
log4perl.logger.test_app               = INFO, FileAppndr1
log4perl.appender.FileAppndr1          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.FileAppndr1.filename = /tmp/test_app.log
log4perl.appender.FileAppndr1.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout
```

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use IPC::Open3;
use Log::Log4perl;
use Symbol 'gensym'; # Create anonymous glob (filehandle)

Log::Log4perl::init("/tmp/log4perl.conf");
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("test_app");
$logger->info('-'x40); # New run

my @tasks = (
    [ 'ls', '-lt', '/tmp/test_app.log' ], # ok
    [ 'df', '-h'                       ], # ok
    [ 'grep', 'foo', '/var/log/foo'    ], # error
);

for my $task (@tasks) {
    run_command($task);
}

sub run_command {
    my ($command_with_args) = @_;
    my ($writer, $reader, $error);
    $error = gensym;
    my $pid = open3($writer, $reader, $error, @$command_with_args);

    waitpid( $pid, 0 );
    my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;

    $logger->info("Running [ " . join(' ', @$command_with_args) . " ]");

    {
        local $/; # Read all of $reader/$error at one go, but do not affect rest of program
        if ($child_exit_status) {
            $logger->error("ERROR: Got status code [ $child_exit_status ]");
            $logger->error("Error Message:\n" . <$error>);
        } else {
            $logger->info("SUCCESS");
            $logger->info("Output:\n" . <$reader>);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** - /tmp/test_app.log

```
INFO - ----------------------------------------
INFO - Running [ ls -lt /tmp/test_app.log ]
INFO - SUCCESS
INFO - Output:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 felix felix 29129 Oct 24 00:06 /tmp/test_app.log

INFO - Running [ df -h ]
INFO - SUCCESS
INFO - Output:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2       30G   13G   18G  41% /
devtmpfs        3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
/dev/xvdh       100G   25G   76G  25% /data/home

INFO - Running [ grep foo /var/log/foo ]
ERROR - ERROR: Got status code [ 2 ]
ERROR - Error Message:
grep: /var/log/foo: No such file or directory
```